# spamassassin + amavisd not filtering

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, amavis

My problem is: my spamassassin look like not working at all, 
no X_SPAM header adding for email, GTUBE test failed, i dont know exactly , 
 but seem's like it's broken after installing spamassassin from wheezy  backports. 
Probably amavisd-new dont work correctly with new spamassassin version.
Feel free to ask for addditional configuration files.
spamassassin --lint no error's.

here my conf files:

pastebin.com/XPNebhD1  - my software versions 
pastebin.com/XfeJ3zpa - master.cf 
pastebin.com/HHPh3FZz  - 50-user 
pastebin.com/kBpDeBBH  - local.cf 
pastebin.com/qJvBjDiQ - dovecot.conf

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in wrong port number in postfix config, changing content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026 to content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024 solved my issue.